# SQL script to UNION a large number of tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.3

I have to do a union of a large number of disjoint daily tables from 2012-12-17 to 2012-10-30 in this example.  The code for this gets ugly here is the snippet:

```
CREATE table map 
with (appendonly=true, compresstype = quicklz)
AS
 SELECT * FROM final_map_12_17
    UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM final_map_12_16
    UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM final_map_12_15
    UNION ALL
     SELECT * FROM final_map_12_14
    UNION ALL
....
SELECT * FROM final_map_10_30;
```

Can I do this type of thing with a sequence or PL/PGSQL function instead of writing out each individual select by hand?

Comment: Use the system catalog to loop for each time you find a table LIKE 'final_map%' concate the name onto a union all select * from <TABLENAME FOUND> execute once your outer loop is done finding tables.  Do this in plsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over date range in plpgsql function like this:

```
create or replace function add_map(date_from date, date_to date)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    day date;
begin
    for day in 
        select generate_series(date_from, date_to, '1 day')
    loop
        execute 'insert into map select * from final_map_'|| 
            to_char(extract(month from day), '09')|| '_' || 
            to_char(extract(day from day), '09');
    end loop;
end; $$;
```

Calling the function:

```
-- create table map (....);
select add_map('2012-11-30', '2012-12-02');
```

is equivalent to:

```
insert into map select * from final_map_11_30;
insert into map select * from final_map_12_01;
insert into map select * from final_map_12_02;
```

Comment: I had to make some modifications from the generate_series because I am on postgresql 8.3

Comment: create or replace function table_union(date_from date, date_to date, numday int)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    day_1 date;
    _stop_ bigint := (date_from::date - date_to::date)::int; 
begin
-- execute 'this is' _stop_;
    for day_1 in 
        select date_from + s.a as dates from generate_series(0, $3 ) as s(a)
    loop
        execute 'insert into dhcp.dhcp_map select * from dhcp.final_map_'|| trim( leading ' ' from to_char(extract(month from day_1), '09'))
    end loop;
end; $$;

Comment: I could not figure out how to pass the variable stop as the argument for generate_series(0, stop) instead of the generate_series(0,$3) is this possible to do easily in plpgsql?

Comment: `declare stop integer := (date_from - date_to); ` should be ok.

Comment: Or just `select date_from + s.a as dates from generate_series(0, date_from - date_to) as s(a)` - without any variable.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a SQL function that would do this.

I would recommend that you put the list of tables in Excel.  Then put in a formula such as:

```
="select * from "&a1&" union all"
```

Copy this formula down.  Voila!  You almost have the view defniition.

Copy the column with these statements into the SQL command tool.  Add the `create view` at the top.  Remove the `union all` at the end.  And voila.  You can easily create the view.

Answer (score 1):

Have a think about redefining your list of tables as a partitioned table, with a single master table and multiple child tables. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Alternatively, maintain a view to union all the tables together, and when you add a new table to the schema add it to the view also.